# how can I add colorpicker on the default rich text editor of grapesjs to change font colors?

Tags: rich-text-editor, rte, grapesjs

I'm going to change the font color using a color picker and I added it like this. but it's not working now. I think It's because the'rte.exec()' please help me how to change the font color. Thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UmZK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Inside init method**strong text**

```
grapesjs.init({
  colorPicker: {
    appendTo: 'parent',
    offset: { top: 26, left: -166, },
  },

});
```